# How do I make this Bash argument from an if statement into a case statement?

Tags: bash, scripting, centos7

I am using a text file called tps_report2 and I want to print out the statement "Please complete the $assignment_name assignment" where the variable $assignment_name would be a name of an assignment, however, if the user leaves the parameter empty, then it would have the variable fill in the word "following" as a default argument.

Here is the correct if else statement:

```
   if [ $# -lt 1 ]
   then
         assignment_name="following"
   else
         assignment_name=$1
   fi
```

Now here is what I tried so far to turn it into a case statement.

```
   while [$# -lt 1]
   do
        case assignment_name
        in
        *) assignment_name="following"
        esac
   done
```

Comment: What about `echo "Please complete the ${assignment_name:-following} assignment"`?

Answer (score 1):

You could:

```
assignment_name="following"
if [ $# -eq 1 ]
then
    assignment_name=$1
fi
```

You can modify the `-eq 1` to `-gt 0`, depending on what you are expecting in arguments.

---

As presented, I would not use a `case` here.  `case` is useful when a variable can have a number of well defined values you can test on.  Using `case` avoids having a long list of `if` statements.  It is a more compact way to replace `if, then, if, then, if, ...`.

But if you insist

```
case $# in
    0)
        assignment_name="following"
    ;;
    1)
        assignment_name="$1"
    ;;
    *)
        echo "ERROR: arguments can be empty, or the name of 1 assignment."
        exit 1
    ;;
esac
```